# Why is the dynamic_cast allowed to yield a null-pointer for polymorphic classes when the destination pointer is not of the type of a base class?

Tags: c++, polymorphism, c++17, dynamic-cast, nullptr

Consider the following program

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

struct A
{
};

struct C
{
};

int main()
{
    C *pc = nullptr;

    A *pa1 = dynamic_cast<A *>( pc );

    std::cout << "pa1 == nullptr is " << std::boolalpha << ( pa1 == nullptr ) << '\n';

    A *pa2 = pc;

    std::cout << "pa2 == nullptr is " << std::boolalpha << ( pa2 == nullptr ) << '\n';
}
```

For the both pointer declarations, pa1 and pa2, the compiler reports an error that such an initialization is not allowed.

For example the clang HEAD 10.0.0 compiler issues the following errors.

```
prog.cc:19:14: error: 'C' is not polymorphic
    A *pa1 = dynamic_cast<A *>( pc );
             ^                  ~~
prog.cc:23:8: error: cannot initialize a variable of type 'A *' with an lvalue of type 'C *'
    A *pa2 = pc;
       ^     ~~
2 errors generated.
```

Now let's make the class C a polymorphic class.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

struct A
{
};

struct C
{
    virtual ~C() = default; 
};


int main()
{
    C *pc = nullptr;

    A *pa1 = dynamic_cast<A *>( pc );

    std::cout << "pa1 == nullptr is " << std::boolalpha << ( pa1 == nullptr ) << '\n';

    A *pa2 = pc;

    std::cout << "pa2 == nullptr is " << std::boolalpha << ( pa2 == nullptr ) << '\n';
}
```

And only the second declaration produces an error. The `dynamic_cast` works.

```
rog.cc:22:8: error: cannot initialize a variable of type 'A *' with an lvalue of type 'C *'
    A *pa2 = pc;
       ^     ~~
1 error generated.
```

What is the reason of that such a conversion of pointers for the `dynamic_cast` is allowed?

Comment: Hypothetically, there could be a class tha inherits from both A and C and thus casting from C* to A* via dynamic casting is valid - as the casting in general doesn't necessarily fail.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> What is the reason of that such a conversion of pointers for the `dynamic_cast` is allowed?

Because `dynamic_cast` runs at run time, and it's too late to issue a  compiler error by then.

If the conversion fails, `dynamic_cast` returns `nullptr`.  You need to check for that and then handle that if needed.

Comment: So it is impossible to distinguish when the source pointer was initially equal to nullptr and when the conversion was incorrect is not it?

Comment: @VladfromMoscow For that you can check the source pointer before the conversion.  Otherwise yes, you wouldn't know if it was a failure or if you just received a null pointer.