# Why is dynamic_cast'ing between pointers from different type hierarchies well defined?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

This is a follow up question to: [Why is the dynamic_cast allowed to yield a null-pointer for polymorphic classes when the destination pointer is not of the type of a base class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59849453/why-is-the-dynamic-cast-allowed-to-yield-a-null-pointer-for-polymorphic-classes).

The C++17 standard specifies `dynamic_cast` under [§8.2.7 *[expr.dynamic.cast]*](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/expr.dynamic.cast).

§8.2.7 (1) states

> The result of the expression `dynamic_cast<T>(v)` is the result of converting the expression v to type T. T shall be a pointer or reference to a complete class type, or “pointer to cv void”. [...]

(2) specifies the value categories, (3) cv conversion within the same type and (4) the `nullptr` case. Every other paragraph of *[expr.dynamic.cast]* is tied to polymorphic types within the same type hierarchy.

I'm not aware of any use case for `dynamic_cast` other than casting between types within the same type hierarchy. Given the following types:

```
struct A
{
    virtual ~A() = default;
};

struct B : A
{
    virtual ~B() = default;
};
```

`A*` can be cast to `B*`, which is probably the most common use case for `dynamic_cast`:

```
A* ptr = new B;
dynamic_cast<B*>(ptr);
```

I expect this to compile because `B` and `A` are in the same type hierarchy (`B` is derived from `A`). In a well defined program a pointer of type `A*` can point to an object of type `B`.

Now lets remove the base class:

```
struct C
{
    virtual ~C() = default;
};

struct D
{
    virtual ~D() = default;
};
```

Surprisingly, the `dynamic_cast` is still allowed:

```
C* ptr;
dynamic_cast<D*>(ptr);
```

I can't see any reason how such a cast couldn't be ill-formed (thus resulting in a compiler error). As far as I know, in a well defined programm, there is no possible way that `ptr` can point to an object of type `D`.

Why is such a cast allowed? Why isn't this forbidden by the standard?

Comment: The compiler doesn't even need to emit any run-time code for the `C*` to `D*` case, it knows at compile time that the types aren't related and can immediately load `nullptr`.

Comment: Behaviour of the program is undefined because you're casting a pointer with indeterminate value.

Comment: @MarkRansom well [clang](https://godbolt.org/z/yxYFPZ) doesn't optimize it completely. Although the assembly looks strange to me.

Comment: @eerorika I know that it is UB. My question is why it's not ill formed.

Comment: @Timo just because it doesn't *need* to emit code doesn't mean it can't.  Might depend on optimization flags too.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The cast from `C*` to `D*` cannot be rejected by the compiler because `dynamic_cast` can cast not only "up" and "down" a class hierarchy, but also "sideways". For example, suppose we have

```
struct E : C, D { };
C* p = new E;
auto q = dynamic_cast<D*>(p);
```

Then `q` will point to the `D` subobject of the complete `E` object containing the `C` object that `p` points to.

This is specified in [[expr.dynamic.cast]/(8.2)](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.dynamic.cast#8.2).

Of course, a sufficiently smart compiler could still warn you, in some cases, that a `dynamic_cast` is guaranteed to fail (if it knows where the pointer comes from).